# "sudo apt-key add -" has no effect

Tags: command-line, 20.04, add-apt-repository

This command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/network -y
```

returns:

```
Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support focal''.
```

Then I'll jump straight to the point by skipping the elementary part of "add-apt-repository" answered and over-answered.

This command:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv A5D712AEE06E6293
sudo gpg -a --export A5D712AEE06E6293 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo bash -c "echo -e 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main\ndeb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-ubuntu-network-wily.list"
```

returns the right output but then when I go to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

returns equally the error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily Release: The following signatures were invalid: DED04C8CBB517AE45B073F12A5D712AEE06E6293
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---------------------------------------- Update ----------------------------------------

The repositories:

```
deb [ trusted=yes allow-insecure=yes allow-weak=yes allow-downgrade-to-insecure=yes check-valid-until=no ] http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
deb-src [ trusted=yes allow-insecure=yes allow-weak=yes allow-downgrade-to-insecure=yes check-valid-until=no ] http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
```

With the command:

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated --allow-insecure-repositories
```

doesn't have effect but the error message becomes shorter:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily Release: The following signatures were invalid: DED04C8CBB517AE45B073F12A5D712AEE06E6293
```

Answer (score 4):

The [PPA in question](https://launchpad.net/%7Eupubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/network) is outdated, its most recent supported Ubuntu release was “wily” (15.10). You should not use such a PPA on any currently supported Ubuntu version.

See also: [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file), especially the [answer by N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110996/250300) might help you.

Comment: `deb [ allow-insecure=yes trusted=yes allow-weak=yes allow-downgrade-to-insecure=yes check-valid-until=no ] http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main` doesn't have effect but the error message becomes shorter:
`GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily Release: The following signatures were invalid: DED04C8CBB517AE45B073F12A5D712AEE06E6293`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the problem from another perspective.

In the first case:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
```

The command:

```
sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
echo $?
```

Returns the error code `100`

```
In the second case:

deb [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
deb-src [trusted=yes] http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu wily main
```

for my surprise, the command:

```
sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
echo $?
```

Give me `0` code. Then I have suspected and tried

```
sudo apt-get install ipscan
```

And command does work!